# wsdl php soap example for respone

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

this is a part of the wsdl:

```
 <message name="addSubscriberRequest">
    <part name="api_key" type="xsd:string"/>
    <part name="group_id" type="xsd:int"/>
    <part name="email" type="xsd:string"/>
    <part name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
 </message>
    <message name="addSubscriberResponse">
    <part name="error" type="tns:ErrorTypeEnum"/>
 </message>

 <operation name="addSubscriber">
     <input message="tns:addSubscriberRequest"/>
     <output message="tns:addSubscriberResponse"/>
 </operation>
```

ok? now i wana send some data to that server:

```
$client = new soapclient('http://mailerlite.com/soapserver.php?wsdl');
$client->addSubscriber('EMtest', 44983, 'name@example.com', 'Name');
```

this code is work currectly...

now

I have this:

```
Return Codes
0: Success - the subscription was successful
1: Invalid email address
100: Invalid API Key
101: Invalid GroupID
201: Is Unsubscribed
202: Is Bounced
```

now how can I get the error code?
I wrote this code but it is wrong...

```
$respone=$client->addSubscriberResponse();
```

Comment: i need to see structure of EnumTypeNum from ur wsdl.

Answer (score 0):

```
$client = new soapclient('http://mailerlite.com/soapserver.php?wsdl');
$response=$client->addSubscriber('EMtest', 44983, 'name@example.com', 'Name');
echo $response;
```

Comment: hi KingAm ... your code do not work.I tryed it before.. I got these error:   ( ! ) Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in G:\wamp\www\tax\getTax.php on line 3

Comment: ok, your response is returning tns:ErrorTypeEnum as per your wsdl instead of string. Thts why it didn't work. we need to make an Object of this type in your php code and then convert it into string. I'll try this and edit answer accordingly. Meanwhile can you paste the "ErrorTypeEnum" structure from wsdl.?

Comment: Please paste the "ErrorTypeEnum" structure from wsdl.